# Why is the read write speed of a Protected DVD so slow?

Tags: encryption

I got a DVD with copy protection enabled on it, but the problem I am facing is that it loads extremely slow. I have seen such happenings with other kinds of protected DVD's as well.

Can anyone tell me why they are slow in loading as compared to the other DVD's. I know that such kind of DVD's utilize `Content Scrambling Systems` (CSS) for protection but why is the loading speed compromised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any encryption technique, decrypting will take longer than reading an unencyrpted or less sophisticatedly protected file. There is no exception with dvds. One way to really see the difference is to rip a dvd from two different computers with different processor speeds. You will notice that the computer with the higher speed will rip the dvd faster.

Comment: This doesn't seem likely. Even the heaviest of encryption algorithms are fast enough not to make it "extremely slow". And CSS uses encryption so weak that software which doesn't officially support it instead simply breaks it in real-time. There is no way that that would result in a slowdown.